# Rails, ZSH - rails and ruby command not found after installing ZSH terminal in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, zsh

I've already installed ruby and rails with rbenv and been using them.
But after I've installed zsh terminal and type '`rails s'`, `'ruby -v'`, etc..,
ZSH said
`'command not found'`.

I think it maybe because of zsh not knowing the 'Path'.

> How can I add the ruby and rails paths to the ZSH in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Of course you have either to set up your PATH or use an explicit path to specify the executable. How should zsh otherwise know where to search for your commands? This is unrelated to macos, but applies to all shells I am aware of.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try adding the following lines to your `.zshrc` file:

```
# Load rbenv if installed
export PATH="${HOME}/.rbenv/bin:${PATH}"
type -a rbenv > /dev/null && eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.

I run these and works perfectly.

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshenv
echo 'source $HOME/.zshenv' >> ~/.zshrc
exec $SHELL
```